# Regular expression with conditionals in Javascript error -> Invalid regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a regular expression that validates the pattern from A01 to A99.
I came out to this solution:

```
^A(?(?=0)0[1-9]|[0-9][0-9])$
```

Then, when I'm trying to implement it into JS I get an error that says

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^A(?(?=0)0[1-9]|[0-9][0-9])$/: Invalid group
at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
at window.onload ((index):34)
```

I have tried doing:

```
new RegExp('^A(?(?=0)0[1-9]|[0-9][0-9])$');
```

Or

```
/^A(?(?=0)0[1-9]|[0-9][0-9])$/
```

But I get the same error with both of those. I know that is because of the conditional check inside de Regular Expression. Is there a way I can implement this pattern inside Js? 
It is working on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/g0Qfac/1

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably mean (?:(..)..), which creates a non capture group, instead of (?(..)..), which is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript regex does not support [**conditional constructs**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html).

Use

```
^A(?:0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$
```

Or

```
^A(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `A` - a letter `A`
- `(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)` - either `0` followed with a digit from `1` to `9` or a digit from `1` to `9` followed with any single digit
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Curious why `?:` is needed in the regex?

Comment: @RickHitchcock Not necessary, but best practice when the value captured with the group is not going to be used.